# How many 8-bit strings contains at least two 0's?

Tags: combinatorics

I need help with this question. How many 8-bit strings contains at least two 0's?

I think the answers is $\displaystyle \dbinom{8}{2}2^6 + \dbinom{8}{3}2^5 ... + \dbinom{8}{8}$

I'm not sure. Can someone please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

$\,^8C_n = \binom{8}{n} = \frac{8!}{n!(8-n)!}$ is the count of ways to select $n$ bits to be '0' and the rest to be '1'. There is no need to multiply the binomial terms by anything.  Just count for all $n \in [2..8]$

It is just: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^8 \,^8C_n = \,^8C_2 + \,^8C_3 + \,^8C_4 + \,^8C_5 + \,^8C_6 + \,^8C_7 + \,^8C_8$

However, it's easier to subtract strings with at most 1 from all the possibilities. There $2^8$ ways 8 symbols can each have one of two values.

$$2^8 - (\,^8C_0 + \,^8C_1) \\= 2^8 - \left(1 + 8\right) \\ = 247$$

Comment: I think there was a typo in the previous answer 256 - (1+8)

Comment: In general, for a n bit string: $f(n)=2^n-n-1$